# apache commons pool - how to use a factory that takes arguments

Tags: pool, apache-commons-pool

I am trying to use apache commons pool to create a pool of 'objects'.  Since I already have an object factory which takes a string type argument and create a right type of object I want to use this factory.

But the problem is that none of the signatures of generic pool object allow me to pass a factory which takes arguments.

```
//This is a wrapper class that holds an Object pool
Class INService {

    private ObjectPool<INConnection> pool_ = null;

    /**
     * Constructs an instance of INService, given a pool size 
     * and a class which implements INHandler interface.
     * @param poolSize - size of the service pool 
     * @param c - the class which handles the INHandler service interface.
     */
    public INService(int poolSize, String objectType) {

        pool_ = new GenericObjectPool<INConnection>(factory, Objecttype); // won't compile.
    }
    ...
}
```

The PoolableObjectfactory interface defines methods like makeObject, destroyObject, validateObject, activateObject and passivateObject.  But no makeObject() method which takes parameters.

It seems that the only way I can do this is to write multiple factory classes for each type of object and write an if-else stuff, like:

```
    public INService(int poolSize, String objectType) {

        if (objectType.equals("scap")
            pool_ = new GenericObjectPool<INConnection>(scapFactory);
        else if (objectType.equals("ucip")
            pool_ = new GenericObjectPool<INConnection>(ucipFactory);
        ...
    }
```

Or, is there any elegant way, instead of duplicating/creating several factory classes just for this sake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on the [`KeyedObjectPool<K,V>`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/KeyedObjectPool.html) interface which can also be found in commons-pool.

From its javadoc:

```
A keyed pool pools instances of multiple types. Each type may be accessed using an arbitrary key.
```

You could then implement a `KeyedPoolableObjectFactory<K,V>` to make instances based on the `key` parameter, it has the [`makeObject(K key)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/KeyedPooledObjectFactory.html#makeObject-K-) function you are looking for.

PS: It appears you haven't marked any answers to your questions as "accepted", you might want to work on that.

Comment: How did u set the parameters for keyPool? like these: 
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory.html

Comment: @neoeahit I can't remember if I did it using one of the [constructors of `GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPoolFactory.html#constructor_summary) or through the [constructors for `GenericKeyedObjectPool`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericKeyedObjectPool.html#constructor_summary), you'll have to try. Or did you want to know something else?